# Android application - LVL testing

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have an android application.

I have programmed the LVL integration as the google documentation recommends. Now I would like to test it, and I'm doing as  google says.

In the developer console I change the kind of license's response: LICENSED, NO_LICENSED...

But the answer that I always receive from google play is LICENSED, even when I have set the kind of response to NO_LICENSED.

I've read in the google documentation that this is because my application is still a draft.

But this has no sense for me as I would like to test my application before publishing it.

How can  I test the application before publishing it and before it is available to final users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very sure why now is working for me. Yesterday, I published and unpublished the application, and I set only one email address in the test accounts.

I don't know if this answer could help anyone, but this is what I did.